# Tomcat 7 - Creating multiple instances of specific Realm per Host

Tags: java, tomcat

I am struggling with realms in Tomcat 7. And after hours of digging, *stackoverflow* is the my last chance to find a sollution or an answer ,)

Let's say I have two applications with their own definitions of `org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm` with different parameters (`digest`, `userTable` and so on) defined within `app/META-INF/context.xml` file. Both applications are deployed within the same `Host`.

My "problem" is that both applications share the one realm (the one which is being instantiated as the first one). I was not able to find anything about instantiation of realms in Tomcat's documentation.
Is it even possible to tell Tomcat to create singleton instance of the realm defined within `Context` element? Or just Tomcat striclty creates singleton instances (one per realm's `className`) for entire `Host`/`Engine` no matter where they are defined?

Thank you.

//EDIT: SSO valve was enabled. This caused the issue.

Comment: As the wiki explains, putting the realm in the application's context.xml is the way to actually get that done; if you'd want only one that is shared among several applications you'd put it in the server.xml file. http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/TomcatDataSourceRealms . How do you test that both applications get the same datasource realm? How do you deploy the applications?

Comment: Hello Gimby.
I was doing everything wrong :( There was the SSO valve enabled within my host. And this valve caused all my troubles. Thank you for kicking me forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was related to SSO valve which was enabled that time.

If SSO is enabled, only one instance of the realm is used for the whole host. See [Tomcat's documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Single_Sign_On).

Thank you!